# cannot access ACI restful endpoint deployed to VN

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, acr

I deployed a docker image to an ACR and then to an ACI with a command like this:

```
az container create 
    --resource-group myrg
    --name myamazingacr 
    --image myamazingacr.azurecr.io/test3:v1 
    --cpu 1 
    --memory 1 
    --vnet myrg-vnet 
    --vnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 
    --subnet default 
    --subnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/24 
    --registry-login-server myamazingacr.azurecr.io 
    --registry-username xxx
    --registry-password xxx
    --ports 80
```

This all works without error and the IP of the ACI is 10.0.0.5 and there is no FQDN as it is a VN. I think this makes sense.

When I run the image outside Azure (i.e. on my local machine where I created the image) I can successfully access an endpoint like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/plot
http://127.0.0.1/predict_petal_length?petal_width=3
```

[127.0.0.1] indicates that I run the image on the local machine.

However, this does not work:

```
http://10.0.0.5/plot
http://10.0.0.5/predict_petal_length?petal_width=3
```

I get:

```
This site can’t be reached10.0.0.5 took too long to respond.
```

What could be wrong please?

PS:

Maybe it is related to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/299493/azure-container-instance-does-not-resolve-name-wit.html

I have to say I find Azure really frustrating to work with. Nothing really seems to work. Starting with Azure ML to ACIs ...

PPS:

this is what our IT says - tbh I do not fully understand ...

•   Private endpoints are not supported so we need to create a vnet in the resource group peer it to the current dev vnet and we should be good
•   We basically need to know how we can create an ACR with the network in an existing vnet in a different resource group. I am struggling to find the correct way to do this.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu - sorry waiting for our IT who say that it may require peering of our 2 VNETs - hopefully more clarity this week ...

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for your issue is that you set the wrong IP address for your application to listen to. The IP address `127.0.0.1` is a localhost or loopback IP that only can be used inside the machine. Take a look [here](https://www.lifewire.com/network-computer-special-ip-address-818385). So you can try to change the IP into `0.0.0.0`. This one is accessible outside.

Comment: sorry I meant that the image work locally!

Comment: @cs0815 Do you mean the image works well in your local machine? If so, the image must be OK. Do you check if you can access the container inside the ACI?

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Curious how do I access the container inside an ACI. All I get is the exposed (plumber) restful endpoint, which cannot be reached.

Comment: @cs0815 Inside the ACI, you can access the rest api with url like `localhost/plot`.

Comment: Sorry I understand that the ACI is probably a VM but how can I rdp into it? is this possible?

Comment: @cs0815 It's impossible. You only can create the session with the command `/bin/bash` or `cmd.exe`.

Comment: intrigued now - is there a link to this pls? I use windows so cmd.exe would be used I guess but i tend to use mstsc ...

Comment: @cs0815 It's just a container, so the ACI does not install the rdp server. Of course, if you install the rdp with a custom image, you also can use the rdp.

Comment: @cs0815 Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Apologies but your answer is very much appreciated but I already told you that I do not access 127.0.0.1. W.r.t. to the second part in the comments. I still do not understand what you mean. Once the image is deployed in the ACI, which I can do, I cannot really rdp into it. There is: az container logs --resource-group myResourceGroup --name bla which maty allow me to glean some logs. This is something I may try.

Comment: @cs0815 If you don't install the RDP when you create the image. You can't RDP to the ACI and there is no way. So if you want to RDP to the ACI, you need to install the RDP when you create the image.

Comment: Thanks now I get you sorry. The images tend to be linux based and the issue is that I cannot  access the exposed endpoints in the vnet so I would think I can also not rdp etc.

Comment: @cs0815 Linux container generally uses the SSH to connect to. And you need to check if the ACI is deployed in the VNet. Then check if the container is in the running state. Otherwise, you can use the Azure CLI command `az container exec` to connect to the container.